# Firefox automatically downloads *and opens* executable files

Tags: windows, firefox

Since some of the recent versions Firefox has directly downloaded seemingly all executable files instead of displaying the Windows' "save the file to..." prompt. The files are downloaded to `\AppData\Local\Temp` (`%TMP%`) and opened in my PDF client, Sumatra PDF:

[image: .exe is opened in Sumatra PDF]

Firefox is set to "always ask you where to save files":

[image: "Always ask you where to save files"]

EXE files aren't associated with any program in Firefox (which of course wouldn't make any sense):

[image: "Applications"]

The associated websites include the [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/), [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) and [MusicBrainz Picard](https://picard.musicbrainz.org/) download pages.

Comment: If you backup your current Firefox user profile, delete the folder, then launch Firefox does the behavior continue?  Please edit your question to include this vital required information.

Comment: @Ramhound: I can verify that the behavior persists with the addons disabled. I will next backup and refresh Firefox.

Comment: @Ramhound: [I created a new profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles), downloads then function as expected. Confirmed as a personal configuration issue.